# Get Target Path of Shortcuts to Recycle Bin or Control Panel

Tags: vbscript, windows-7, shortcut

The following code gets the target path of regular shortcuts.

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objShellLink = objShell.CreateShortcut(WScript.Arguments(0))
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

strTargetPath = objShellLink.TargetPath

If (objFSO.FileExists(strTargetPath)) Then  ' A link to a file.
    Set objF = objFSO.getFile(strTargetPath)
Else        ' A link to a folder.
    Set objF = objFSO.getFolder(strTargetPath)
End If

strFolderToOpen = """" & objF.ParentFolder & """"
strItemToSelect = """" & objF.Name & """"
```

The `objShellLink.TargetPath` for some shortcuts (e.g `Recycle Bin.lnk`, `Control Panel.lnk`) is empty.

How can I get the target path of those shortcuts?

Comment: Can't understand what your code does at all. What do you want to do? Get target path of what shortcut? And how do you execute your script? Using what version of windows script host? command line or windows based?

Comment: Then what is the purpose of getting that path? Asking because there are many alternative ways to do what you want instead of doing it this way.

Comment: `Open File Location` in Explorer's context-menu is displayed without pressing `Shift`. As it's a `ShellEx` command I couldn't find a way to have it displayed only **with `Shift`** and that's purpose of the script: I've added an `Open File Location` command to `lnkfile - Shell` (with `Extended`) and the script is executed from Explorer's context-menu. *** Thanks Again. ***

Comment: Did you mean something like that ? https://superuser.com/questions/395015/how-to-open-the-recycle-bin-from-the-windows-command-line/395140

Comment: If you create a shortcut to a regular file/folder and open its `Properties`, you'd see a `Target` field. If, however, you create a shortcut to `Control Panel`, `Windows Update` or `Recycle Bin` the `Target` field is grayed-out and not passed as an argument. Your suggestion would have been helpful if it was only the `Recycle Bin`; but it was an example. *** Thank you.